# Cannot do make eclipse-project in an existing package

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, eclipse

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have already created a beginner_tutorials package and now i want to install eclipse and created eclipse project files.

After following the instructions, when i do `make eclipse-project` there is an error stating `make: *** No rule to make target 'eclipse-project'. Stop`

This is the same question as [this](https://answers.ros.org/question/222701/cannot-do-make-eclipse-project-in-an-existing-ros-package/) but i did not understand the solution.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/288883/cannot-do-make-eclipse-project-in-an-existing-package./) by [aks](https://answers.ros.org/users/34222/aks/) on ROS Answers with karma: 667 on 2018-04-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Solved : Just went through with the instructions again.

It says : `if you are using catkin, you do not have the possibility to make eclipse-project`. I went ahead with the instructions in 2.2 [here](http://wiki.ros.org/IDEs#Eclipse)

---

Originally posted by [aks](https://answers.ros.org/users/34222/aks/) with karma: 667 on 2018-04-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0